# <af:validateLength > customize the message

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

```
 <af:inputText value="#{bindings.description.inputValue}"
id="ip1" required="true" rows="10" columns="137" 
shortDesc="#{bindings.desc.hints.tooltip}"
maximumLength="300" >
   <af:validateLength maximum="#{bindings.desc.hints.precision}" id="vl2" messageDetailMaximum="custom message"
      />
</af:inputText>
```

when value is typed desc field, there is a message
popping up in the upper right of the field: "Enter between 0 and 300
characters".

How can i change this message. Tried to add the messageDetailMaximum attribute, but the new message is not shown

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to restrict user to 300 characters and NOT to show any faces error messages. Then you can use below code to show note with your custom message.

```
<af:inputText label="Hello" id="it0" value="" maximumLength="5" shortDesc="Note !!">           
      </af:inputText>
```

This code would restrict user to 5 characters and on focus would show a tool tip given in shortDesc attribute .

-Sid

Answer (score 0):

If you have a property file, just add this bundle to it :

```
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM=Custom Validation Error: Minimum length not reached!
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM_detail={0}: Custom Validation The input value {1} is less than the mimimum allowed ({2})
```

If you dont have one, you can check out [this link](http://www.qualogy.com/overriding-default-adf-validation-messages/).